# Gerador de PDF com Framework Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, mvc, pdf, laravel-rotas

Eu preciso fazer o `snappy` gerar relatórios a partir dos dados do `BD`. Mas pra isso eu precisava de exemplos de uso do `snappy`, na documentação do [github](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/blob/master/readme.md) até tem um exemplo, mas aquele exemplo não me ajudou. Precisava de um exemplo de como usar o `Snappy` com `controller`, `views` e `rotas`. Alguém pode me ajudar, por favor?

@@Edit

*Não precisa ser exatamente esse, é que eu vi no `Laracasts` que era o melhor gerador de `PDF`. Vou dar uma olhada na documentação do [dompdf](https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf). De qualquer forma, se eu utilizar o [dompdf](https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) você teria um código de exemplo como eu disse a cima? Obrigada desde já*

Comment: Precisa ser exatamente esse gerador de PDF, ele tem uma coisa que eu não gosto que é a instalação dependente de sistema? por exemplo esse é bem simples [barryvdh/laravel-dompdf](https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Exemplo minimo:***

Instalação do pacote [barryvdh/laravel-dompdf](https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf)

> `composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`

Após a conclusão da instalação, entre no arquivo `app/config.php` e adicione as seguintes configurações:

```
'providers' => [ 
    ....
    Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
]
```

**e**

```
'aliases' => [
    ...
    'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
]
```

volte a linha de comando e digite:

> `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider"`

para que seja publicada as configurações na pasta `config` o arquivo `dompdf.php`.

***Observação:*** existe uma pasta no pacote da instalação que deve ser copiada manualmente para a pasta `storage` do [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel), essa pasta contem os arquivos de fontes utilizados por esse pacote para geração dos relatórios em `PDF` e o caminho é
`vendor\dompdf\dompdf\lib` e a pasta é `fonts`, ficando com esse aspecto.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois do processo de instalação e configuração crie um `controller` por exemplo:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Stackoverflow;
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;

class PdfviewController extends Controller
{

    private $model;
    public function __construct(Stackoverflow $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['model'] = $this->model->all();
        return PDF::loadView('view', $data)
            ->stream();
    }
}
```

a rota:

```
Route::get('/viewpdf', 'PdfviewController@index');
```

e sua View com essa estrutura, gerando uma lista de informações da tabela `stackoverflow`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Laravel</title>
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Styles -->
    <style>
        html, body {
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #636b6f;
            font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 100;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .full-height {
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .flex-center {
            align-items: center;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .position-ref {
            position: relative;
        }

        .top-right {
            position: absolute;
            right: 10px;
            top: 18px;
        }

        .content {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .title {
            font-size: 84px;
        }

        .links > a {
            color: #636b6f;
            padding: 0 25px;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: 600;
            letter-spacing: .1rem;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        .m-b-md {
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Descrição</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($model as $item)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$item->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$item->description}}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

tendo a saída:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [barryvdh/laravel-dompdf](https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf)
- [DOMPDF Wrapper for Laravel 5](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf)

Comment: oi, estou tentando implementar essa resposta que voce postou aqui. me diz uma coisa: `App\Stackoverflow;` pode ser qualquer model que eu tenha?

Comment: outra questão: qual deve ser o nome da view.blade?

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo pode ser qualquer model, e pode estar em qualquer namespace, só precisa realmente ser os dados que vão gerar a sua tela.

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo o nome é da sua preferencia, qualquer nome, me diz qual sua dificuldade em montar esse exemplo, está dando algum erro?

Comment: oi, fiz o teste agora e gerou o pdf sim. a questão é que ele não informou na tela e eu não percebi. abraço